# Execute Fortran subroutine through parallel Python impossible to execute

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, fortran, parallel-python

I am trying to execute a Fortran subroutine in Python 2.7 using parallel python (PP package). But when I execute it using pp.server().submit(...) nothing happens. I might have implemented it wrong, I have used the `numpy.f2py.compile()` as explained [here](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/f2py/usage.html#python-module-numpy-f2py). Is this correct? And if not, what should I change?

Just to mention that the code is almost surely correct given that it is taken from a doctorate thesis ([code](https://github.com/paulilhe/shot_noise), [paper](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-01494334/file/manuscrit.pdf)).

The subroutine implemented in a Python 2.7 module called "design_operation" is:

```
import numpy.f2py
fsource = '''
subroutine matrix_op(grid_x,grid_t,eval_grid,pas,K,L,M,C)
  COMPLEX :: i=(0.0,1.0)
  INTEGER , intent(in) :: K,L,M
  REAL , intent(in) :: pas
  INTEGER :: u,v,w
  REAL , dimension(1:M) , intent(in) :: grid_x
  REAL , dimension(1:K) , intent(in) :: grid_t
  REAL , dimension(1:L) , intent(in) :: eval_grid
  COMPLEX, dimension(1:L,1:M) , intent(out) :: C

  do u=1,L
     do v=1,M
        do w=1,K
           C(u,v) = C(u,v) - i*pas*grid_t(w)*grid_x(v)*exp(-i*grid_t(w)*grid_x(v)*eval_grid(u))
        end do
     end do
  end do
  end subroutine matrix_op
  '''
numpy.f2py.compile(fsource, modulename='design_operation', verbose=0)
```

Then, I call it this way:

```
job_server.submit(func=list_append,
                                  args=(grid_x, grid_t, sub_eval[k,:], pas_f,),
                                  modules=('numpy as np','design_operation as fdp',)
```

which is actually in a loop and should be executed in:

```
job_server = pp.Server()
thread_number = job_server.get_ncpus()
...some unimportant code ...
jobs = []
for k in range(thread_number): 
    jobs.append(job_server.submit(func=list_append,
                                  args=(grid_x, grid_t, sub_eval[k,:], pas_f,),
                                  modules=('numpy as np','design_operation as fdp',)))

for i,job in enumerate(jobs):
    if i == 0:
        dM = job() 
    else:
        dM = np.concatenate((dM, job()))

job_server.destroy()
return dM
```

I always get the following error:

> zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated.

Therefore I suppose that the error comes from the incorrect execution of the tasks, but perhaps am I mistaking.

The stack error is:

```
An error has occured during the function execution
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\project\lib\site-packages\ppworker.py", line 90, in run
    __result = __f(*__args)
  File "<string>", line 2, in list_append
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'matrix_op'
An error has occured during the function execution
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\project\lib\site-packages\ppworker.py", line 90, in run
    __result = __f(*__args)
  File "<string>", line 2, in list_append
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'matrix_op'
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-89-6cb5b50fd813>", line 5, in <module>
    dM = np.concatenate((dM, job()))#

ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated
```

PS: I supposed there is some unnecessary code and therefore I didn't include it for more clarity + the arguments of func= list_append are correct.

Comment: Can you edit in the full stack trace of the error?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the parallel python package, but somewhat with F2PY. You get an error message that "'module' object has no attribute 'matrix_op'", that could indicate that the function is not being loaded. You import the F2PY module _design_operation_ as _fdp_, but you do not show where the `fdp.matrix_op` is being used? How is `list_append` defined in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice your code doesn't seem to pass the `K, L, M` and `C` variables to the Fortran routine. However, `K, L, M` are used to dimension some arrays and are also used as loop counters. It's quite possible that these values are set to a default value of `0` by the compiler, or maybe more likely as `None` by Python itself. That would explain your error message `ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated'.

Comment: F2PY creates wrappers so that a Fortran subroutine can be called like a Python function (i.e. the intent(out) argument `C` becomes the return value of the function), and dimensions for automatic arrays do not need to be passed explicitly, see [this example in the documentation](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/f2py/python-usage.html#array-arguments). So I don't believe that is the problem in this case.

Comment: @jbdv That surpises me a bit based on my reading of the docs [here](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/f2py/signature-file.html#attributes) (see 'intent', especially 'in', 'out', and 'hide'). Not to say that things don't 'work out' in some cases even without doing so. I'd have to experiment to know more.

Comment: As I read that, `C` which is `intent(out)` in Fortran, the F2PY _intent out_ and hence _hide_ implies that "The argument is considered as a return variable" and "The argument is removed from the list of required or optional arguments", so when called from Python, `C` should not be passed to the function, but is the function's return value.

Comment: While the arguments defining array dimensions `K`, `L` and `M` are Fortran `intent(in)` and will get the F2PY attributes _intent in_ and _optional_, so that they can, but don't have to, be passed to the wrapped function (but are inferred from and checked against the passed array arguments `grid_t`, `eval_grid` and `grid_x`). I may very well be wrong, but I believe this is not what's causing the OP's problems

Comment: @jbdv Regarding `C`, I believe we are in agreement - particularly since `C` is the only `intent(out)` variable then `hide` is implied. However, it seems to me that even [the example you linked](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/f2py/python-usage.html#array-arguments) illustrates how `intent(in)` array dims must be handled explicitly to avoid issues (in that example, the interface defines how the array length is to be handled, which allows it to be optional). That's not done in the OP's code. Aside: By now, I think I could have just run an experiment, but I haven't :)

Comment: I probably didn't choose the clearest example :) The point I wanted to make was that in that Python example, `arr.foo` was only passed the array `A`, not the array bounds `m` and `n`, that should also be the same in OP's case. First building and inspecting a signature file for the OP's Fortran code, shows what I expected, and then building and importing this into Python and printing the function's `__doc__` string, seems to indicate everything is recognised by F2PY as it should. But I also haven't tested further than that :)